# Best way to convert this flash application to iphone compatible?

Tags: iphone, ios, html, flash, canvas

I have an interactive flash animation which i need to be able to use on an iPhone, embedded within an iPhone app.

I'm not able to link the animation here but a screenshot of the interface (which is pretty self explanitory) can be found here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkNRO.jpg

It's a very simple interaction with just dragging answers into boxes and checking whether the answers are correct. My question is what would the easiest/best way to convert this to something that can be used on the iPhone?

My initial thoughts would be to use Canvas but i've not looked deeply into what it can do so I was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Your file is not opening. It throws error of HTTP Status 403 - invalid session.

Comment: Yeah, realised it was only working because I was logged in.. Edited it with a screenshot instead.

Answer (score 1):

Flash embeds logic inside it via scripts. What you are referring to is not an "animation" but a working application.

You should check this [link](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html) if you use Actionscript 3, I never did that myself.
If the scenario of the app is as you describe, then using your flash sources inside your iOS app shouldn't be too difficult to achieve IMHO.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion between animation and application, i'll change the title.

Unfortunately i don't have the code for the existing application so i'm not sure that i'd be able to use that link that you've sent me.